# Opening IE Browser from C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

I can open a new IE browser via this code:

```
var IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
        object URL = "http://google.com";

        IE.ToolBar = 0;
        IE.StatusBar = false;
        IE.MenuBar = true;
        IE.AddressBar = true;
        IE.Width = 622;
        IE.Height = 582;
        IE.Visible = true;
        IE.Navigate2(ref URL);
```

That part and the sizing work fine but I am unable to set the location the window.

I need to open about 5 new individual IE browsers and all must be in different locations across the screen.

What is the syntax for the location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using the Left property.
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752056(v=vs.85).aspx][1]

```
   IE.Left = 0;
```